# k type Thermocouple for PID controller

Tags: power

I have 2 PID temperature controllers with k type thermocouples. They are attached to separate aluminum plates controlled by the PID on the temperature. One of my thermocouples is reading way up there when the PID show that it reach the desired temperature and shuts off. The set point is 90deg, it reaches that point on the plate and shuts down, then back on to stabilize like its suppose to.

Why is the thermocouple reading keep going up if the PID and SSR are shut down? I also noticed, that plate is hotter then the other one.

[image][image][image]

Comment: Do the aluminum plates have heaters in them? How big are the aluminum plates? How far away from the heaters are the K thermocouples attached? Can you provide a photo or circuit drawing? Thanks.

Comment: let me switch the one heating element around and see if that solves the problem.. weird tho because they are AC. some how its keeps constant power instead of communicating with the PID and shutting off the power

Comment: they are 3x5 aluminum plates

Comment: AC 110v 100w heating elements

Comment: 2- Inkbird 106vh PID TEMPERATURE CONTROLLERS with 2- SSR 40 DA relays

Comment: I am a little confused what your question is. You say the thermocouple reading is high but the block also feels hotter than expected? Does the heater ssr actually shut off? Nice build

Comment: confusing right... the SSR shuts down, but yet the block still keeps getting hotter.. the thermocouple is reading it.. so at first i thought it was the thermocouple.. well that cant be, right? the prob must be wit the relay or the heating element right???

Comment: so im think i should either check all my connections first off.. make sure i wired it right.. if still happening then change SSR.. if still happening then change the heating element.. if still happening im going to take my shotgun to it... start over

Comment: In the photo the thermocouple transition fitting is crimped pretty good around the braid. It may be shorting through the fiberglass insulation inside and measuring the transition fitting temperature instead of the inside of the block. If you warm up only the thermocouple crimped fitting and the temperature reading jumps up then you have a short at the crimp.

Comment: if you have a clamp on current meter easy to check heater current, or check voltage with a multimeter

Comment: i bought the couplers off the internet... however the problem im having is the heating element constantly staying on when its not suppose to... heating up way past the point of set temperature.. set for 90 but it keeps going all way past 300 degrees..  so its not the thermocouple.. its reading correct..its either the PID, SSR, or i need to switch the heating element around.. meaning i wired it backwards.

Comment: now i got an even weirder problem.. when i lift the lid to look inside 1 PID suddenly says ORAL.... close the lid and its jus fine.. what in the hell is going on??

Comment: Does it stop at some temperature? For example when it reaches 350 degrees does it stop? Or do you have to turn off the power to keep the aluminum block from melting?  If it cycles the heater on and off, but does a poor job of stabilizing the temperature then that is exactly what you could expect if you were measuring the temperature a long distance from the heat source. Overshoot will happen when there is a long time lag for the heat to travel across the aluminum block.

Answer (score 0):

The thermocouple leads may be shorted where it is crimped entering the aluminum block. It may be shorting through the braided fiberglass insulation inside and measuring the transition fitting temperature instead of the inside of the block. If you warm up only the thermocouple crimped fitting and the temperature reading jumps up then you have a short at the crimp.